# When was the concept of large-scale Hechsherim introduced and was it controversial?

Tags: halacha, history, kashrut-kosher, jewish-american-history

Nowadays, Jews in America and Europe often rely on national or regional hechsherim whereby a product is certified as kosher by a rabbi the consumer does not know (and may not even really know who the mashgiach or rabbi is). This seems to me a relatively modern phenomenon. The gemara and early poskim discuss certain cases where we know a specific food item is kosher based on simanim or the concept of a seal as an indication against tampering (e.g., in the chanukah story). But is there early precedent for the concept of an organization or rabbinate vouching for a product or establishment and, especially, sending that product to other locales or throughout a large area who will also rely on the hechsher?

When did the paradigm of modern hechsherim like the OU, star K, etc. first arise? And when they did, was the concept at all controversial? For example, I could imagine objecting that a written symbol doesn't fall within the category of "ed echad" or that an occasional mashgiach can't really be certain everything that's being put in the soda, cookies, peanut butter, etc.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tag "jewish-american-history".

Comment: I would expect more controversy around the idea that an establishment can't be assumed kosher without the approval of a commercial agency.

Comment: https://oukosher.org/blog/articles/celebrating-100-years-of-ou-kosher-a-brief-history/

Comment: @IsraelReader I thought modern hechsherim originated in America. According to Wikipedia, the OU was the first independent kashrut agency.

Comment: @shmosel Yes that too. But I was thinking more about products where they may not be manufactured by religious Jews and/or there may be other people in the chain of distribution, e.g., a jar of peanut butter or a box of pasta.

Comment: The OU may have been the first independent kashrut **agency**. However your question asked about the "*concept of an organization or rabbinate vouching for a product or establishment*". The Rabbinic responsa contain various references to rabbis or Batei Din that certified various products that were being marketed. I belief that this was in Europe, in the 1700s and 1800s. I don't have the time to research it now, but I remember coming across various Teshuvos and stories on this topic.

Comment: @IsraelReader that's certianly all related. If you think the tag is wrong by all means you can delete it.

Comment: The OU recently published a magazine with their history. I think it was an issue of Jewish  Action. The development was gradual. I am not aware of anyone being opposed to kashrut agencies in theory. It just didn't really exist before the industrial revolution because most things were locally made and produced.